Has anyone been able to setup json style logging on Azure Functions?
I'm trying to set up Azure Functions log json logs similar to here. However I haven't been able to get them to work properly. It seems to ignore any attempts at configuring my azure function this way. I'm using a dotnet-isolated environment
I have tried updating the host.json and Program.cs file.
I'm expecting json style logging to output to my console.

I don't see "json logs" if I check the link you provided. What is the problem you are trying to solve? Logs are represented in a different way in console and in Application Insights. Application Insights get logs in JSON with parameters.

Please share your Program.cs and host.json fileS which you tried.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@VladDX Matt is referring to this, which is further down the same page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter#json It's another type of log formatter that's optimised to output JSON.

This works for me:
Program.cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureLogging(builder =>
    {
        builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
        builder.AddJsonConsole(options =>
        {
            options.IncludeScopes = false;
            options.TimestampFormat = "HH:mm:ss ";
            options.JsonWriterOptions = new JsonWriterOptions
            {
                Indented = true
            };
        });
        builder.AddFilter("", LogLevel.Warning); // General log level.
        builder.AddFilter("MyNamespace", LogLevel.Debug); // Namespace-specific
    })
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        // Your services etc
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

And the console output looks like this:
[2024-05-22T15:24:50.942Z] {
[2024-05-22T15:24:50.942Z] Error response [f04bc683-3606-4fab-879f-b5a588e63d7d] 409 The specified container already exists. (00.0s)
[2024-05-22T15:24:50.944Z]   "Timestamp": "16:24:50 ",
[2024-05-22T15:24:50.945Z] Server:Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
[2024-05-22T15:24:50.946Z]   "EventId": 8,
[2024-05-22T15:24:50.948Z] x-ms-request-id:84e5275d-501e-0032-2a5c-ace4fb000000
[2024-05-22T15:24:50.949Z]   "LogLevel": "Warning",
[2024-05-22T15:24:50.950Z] x-ms-client-request-id:f04bc683-3606-4fab-879f-b5a588e63d7d
[2024-05-22T15:24:50.952Z]   "Category": "Azure.Core",
[2024-05-22T15:24:50.953Z] x-ms-version:2022-11-02
[2024-05-22T15:24:50.955Z]   "Message": "Error response [f04bc683-3606-4fab-879f-b5a588e63d7d] 409 The specified container already exists. (00.0s)\r\nServer:Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0\r\nx-ms-request-id:84e5275d-501e-0032-2a5c-ace4fb000000\r\nx-ms-client-request-id:f04bc683-3606-4fab-879f-b5a588e63d7d\r\nx-ms-version:2022-11-02\r\nx-ms-error-code:ContainerAlreadyExists\r\nDate:Wed, 22 May 2024 15:24:36 GMT\r\nContent-Length:230\r\nContent-Type:application/xml\r\n",
[2024-05-22T15:24:50.956Z] x-ms-error-code:ContainerAlreadyExists
[2024-05-22T15:24:50.960Z] Date:Wed, 22 May 2024 15:24:36 GMT
[2024-05-22T15:24:50.958Z]   "State": {
[2024-05-22T15:24:50.962Z] Content-Length:230
[2024-05-22T15:24:50.964Z]     "Message": "Microsoft.Extensions.Azure.AzureEventSourceLogForwarder\u002BEventSourceEvent",
[2024-05-22T15:24:50.965Z] Content-Type:application/xml
[2024-05-22T15:24:50.969Z] 
[2024-05-22T15:24:50.967Z]     "requestId": "f04bc683-3606-4fab-879f-b5a588e63d7d",
[2024-05-22T15:24:50.972Z]     "status": 409,
[2024-05-22T15:24:50.974Z]     "reasonPhrase": "The specified container already exists.",
[2024-05-22T15:24:50.976Z]     "headers": "Server:Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0\r\nx-ms-request-id:84e5275d-501e-0032-2a5c-ace4fb000000\r\nx-ms-client-request-id:f04bc683-3606-4fab-879f-b5a588e63d7d\r\nx-ms-version:2022-11-02\r\nx-ms-error-code:ContainerAlreadyExists\r\nDate:Wed, 22 May 2024 15:24:36 GMT\r\nContent-Length:230\r\nContent-Type:application/xml\r\n",
[2024-05-22T15:24:50.979Z]     "seconds": 0.0144063
[2024-05-22T15:24:50.980Z]   }
[2024-05-22T15:24:50.981Z] }
[2024-05-22T15:24:51.315Z] Added (my log message) at 22/05/2024 16:00:00 +01:00
[2024-05-22T15:24:51.316Z] {
[2024-05-22T15:24:51.318Z]   "Timestamp": "16:24:51 ",
[2024-05-22T15:24:51.320Z]   "EventId": 0,
[2024-05-22T15:24:51.322Z]   "LogLevel": "Information",
[2024-05-22T15:24:51.325Z]   "Category": "MyApplication.MyService",
[2024-05-22T15:24:51.328Z]   "Message": "Added (my log message) at 22/05/2024 16:00:00 \u002B01:00",
[2024-05-22T15:24:51.330Z]   "State": {
[2024-05-22T15:24:51.332Z]     "Message": "Added (my log message) at 22/05/2024 16:00:00 \u002B01:00",
[2024-05-22T15:24:51.334Z]     "{OriginalFormat}": "Added (my log message) at 22/05/2024 16:00:00 \u002B01:00"
[2024-05-22T15:24:51.336Z]   }
[2024-05-22T15:24:51.338Z] }
[2024-05-22T15:24:51.374Z] Executed 'Functions.MyAzureFunction' (Succeeded, Id=987e46df-a482-4ba3-b4f8-b0c227696ceb, Duration=2121ms)
[2024-05-22T15:24:53.416Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000006DB5E4C4'.

This is on .NET 8 isolated.
